# Laravel Session Cookie Expiry Changing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session-cookies, pyrocms

I am running into a problem when my Laravel session-cookie changes expiry time each time I refresh and often expires after 2x refreshes.

I think the expected functionality is for it to expire x minutes after you last interacted with the service, but mine seems to work *very* differently. Let me detail it:

In my Laravel `.env` file I have

```
APP_TIMEZONE="Pacific/Auckland"
```

Accessing PHP via the CLI I get this output with regards to my local time:

```
php -a
Interactive shell
php > echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
2018-12-30 04:08:09
php > echo date_default_timezone_get();
UTC
php > echo date('I');
0
```

The time given above is out by an hour. I think PHP is misconfigured for daylight savings. My cookie access times are also off by an hour as well, because of this I assume.

1. Login (Success)

   - Expires on: `Mon, 31 Dec 2018 03:53:21 GMT`
   - Last accessed on: `Sun, 30 Dec 2018 03:53:21 GMT`
2. Refresh #1 (Success)

   - Expires on: `Sun, 30 Dec 2018 05:53:31 GMT`
   - Last accessed on: `Sun, 30 Dec 05:53:31 GMT`
3. Refresh #2 (Logged Out)

   - Expires on: `Sun, 30 Dec 2018 05:53:39 GMT`
   - Last accessed on: `Sun, 30 Dec 2018 05:53:39 GMT`

Here's a video of it occuring: https://youtu.be/ssPAn5aE0ME

I would have expected that my Expires on value would have been bumped forward to 24 hours ahead of when I last accessed the application (that is what my session timeout is set to).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please, try to set `TIMEZONE=Pacific/Auckland` in your `.env` file. Also I suppose interactive shell doesn't load your `.env` file. Try `tinker` instead.

Comment: Here you go:

    Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.1.19 — cli) by Justin Hileman
    >>> echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    2018-12-31 10:45:17
    >>> echo date_default_timezone_get();
    Pacific/Auckland
    >>> echo date("I");
    1

These values are all accurate to my local timezone, and I've already got this set:

    APP_TIMEZONE="Pacific/Auckland"

Comment: Ya, Laravel Tinker based on the PsyShell actually...

Comment: CLI application access won't effect the browser's session (if I am following you correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this through double and triple checking my timezone settings in my .env file and my PHP ini files.